# Wiremock setup based on spring profiles in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, performance-testing, wiremock

I have run into a probelm with Wiremock setup with spring boot application.

> **Background:**
> Current application setup has wiremock implemented for functional tests(spring profile - `test`) to mock responses for multiple downstream services.

I need to setup **Performance Test Environment (`perf`)** for the application, I will be using different wiremock configurations for `perf` environment .
As there are multiple downstream services involved, I want to simulate delayed response from downstream services to get accurate results. Wiremock provides us with following configuration to do that:

> `"fixedDelayMilliseconds": <x milliseconds>`

(*ref : https://wiremock.org/docs/simulating-faults/*)

But if I include this param in my current wiremock configuration, it will also get applied to functional test(spring profile `test`). Please suggest a way to add this delay based on spring profile only for `perf` but not for `test`.

I am thinking to implement mocked services implementation for `perf` env and add response delays there, but I want to achieve this through configurations, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `WireMockConfigurationCustomizer` when profile `perf` is active and register an extension which is setting that delay instead of setting the delay directly in your wiremock stub definitions.

```java
@Configuration
public class WiremockConfig {

    @Bean
    @Profile("perf")
    public WireMockConfigurationCustomizer wiremockConfig() {
        return config -> config.extensions(
                new ResponseDefinitionTransformer() {
                    @Override
                    public ResponseDefinition transform(Request request, ResponseDefinition response, FileSource fileSource, Parameters parameters) {
                        return ResponseDefinitionBuilder.like(response).withFixedDelay(2000).build();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getName() {
                        return "inject-delay-transformer";
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Will `WireMockConfigurationCustomizer` work for a specific profile (`pref`), for other profiles will it take default configurations?

Comment: Yes. The `@Profile("perf")` annotation makes sure this customizer is only created when that profile is active. If that profile is not active the customizer will not be created and wiremock will run with default configurations.

Comment: `WireMockConfigurationCustomizer`  is a class from `spring-cloud-contract`, is there any similar customization class present with wiremock - `group: 'com.github.tomakehurst', name: 'wiremock-jre8'` as well?

Comment: found `ResponseDefinitionTransformer ` for implementing this

Comment: Yes the configuration with `WireMockConfigurationCustomizer` does only work if you let spring configure wiremock by annotating your test with `@AutoConfigureWireMock`. However  as you mentioned, you can still configure Wiremock manually and add the transformer based on the active profiles.